Will demeaning affect later PSD estimates?
I'm relatively new to signal processing, so if my question reveals some conceptual misunderstanding please do say... I'm just wondering if demeaning (and thus homogenising) my data (recorded from 32 channels with different means and ranges) would help or hinder the accuracy of a later PSD estimate.
Thanks

Since the average is also a part of the PSD: of course it affects the PSD.
The question here is whether you care about the 0 Hz component of the PSD. That I can't tell you; you asking this at all indicates you don't, but then again, what would removing the average then do for you at all?
